# unbound method mainloop() must be called with Tk instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

The below code is a simple code which I tried to check if Tkinter worked...

```
import Tkinter
top=Tkinter.Tk
top.mainloop()
```

Acoording to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.html

this should open a blank window

But the following error message was received

```
  File "b.py", line 3, in <module>
    top.mainloop()
TypeError: unbound method mainloop() must be called with Tk instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Any suggestions...

Comment: You need to do`top=Tkinter.TK()`. Notice the parenthesis. You use them to create _an instance_ of the `Tk()` OBJECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter.Tk() creates an instance of Tk() object which act as argument for mainloop. Do this instead:

```
top = Tkinter.tk() //will open a pop up box
top.mainloop()
```

Read this for further understanding.
    [tkinter-understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)